# Is there partial order over $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that there're two maximal elements and one least element?

Tags: proof-verification, relations

> Let set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Is there such a partial order relation over $A$ such that there're two maximal elements and one least element?

I think we could define a partial order as follows:
$$
xRy \iff x>y \quad \land \quad\text{x and y are prime}
$$
Thus for $A$ we have $\{(3,1), (4,1)\}$. There're no other elements less than $1$ so it's the least element. And this way $3$ and $4$ are maximal elements.

Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I suggest you to study how to draw a Hasse diagram out of an order relation. Those diagrams make it easy to determine maximal/minimal, least/gratest elements, etc. 

Based upon a Hasse diagram the most natural choice would be $$\leq =\{(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4)\},$$ which provides you the $Y$ picture mentioned in the  answer below.

As to your example, there are no least element. You would not have lower bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y

(the partially ordered set whose poset diagram looks like the alphabet Y, where we assume the order is increasing from bottom to top. see below image for more details).

[image]